# Not able to provide input when we use Adaptivecards fabric UI in spfx bot extension

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards, fluentui-react

Not able to provide input when we use AcFabric from adaptivecards-fabric in spfx bot extension
version we are using "adaptivecards-fabric": "^1.1.1",
We are using adaptivecards package with bot framework in spfx solution.
Issue:
When we do not use Fabric controls while rendering Adaptive Cards ,it works fine. But with ACFabric.useFabricComponents() Card do not allow to enter inputs in text field or any other field.

Is there any issue with adaptivecards-fabric library or are we doing anything wrong?

Reference link solution:
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-adaptivecards

Comment: What is your question? Please have a look at this handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: We have open issue in github for this https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/1746